# Queue of snackbars jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

When i call Snackbar multiple times, they create a queue and occure one by one. I want a new Snachbar to immediately close previous one. Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                actionColor = color5,
                snackbarData = data
            )
        }
    },...
```

That`s what documentation says:

> SnackbarHostState guarantees to show at most one snackbar at a time. If this function is called while another snackbar is already visible, it will be suspended until this snack bar is shown and subsequently addressed. If the caller is cancelled, the snackbar will be removed from display and/or the queue to be displayed.

Any ideas how can i switch off this function of SnackbarHost?

Answer (score 8):

You could dismiss the previous snack bar before showing a new one. I don't know whether it is intended for this purpose, but `SnackbarData` interface in `SnackbarHostState`class has a `dismiss()` method:

```
snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
```

Comment: This works as intended.

Comment: it's not working, could you please give me code snippets to understand